# Не переведён текст на страницах ваших недавно удалённых вопросов и ответов

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, профиль-участника

[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/:вашId](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/:%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%88Id)

[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/:вашId](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/:%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%88Id)

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попасть можно со страницы со списком ваших вопросов/ответов.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не переведены и строки, и заголовки страниц.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Утвердил переводы от MSDN.WhiteKnight.

1. https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14188

   > Недавно удалённые вопросы
2. https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14189

   > недавно удалённые вопросы
3. https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14187

   > Нет недавно удалённых вопросов
4. https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14166

   > Недавно удалённые ответы
5. https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14192

   > недавно удалённые ответы
6. https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14177

   > Нет недавно удалённых ответов
7. https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14191

   > На этой странице показаны ваши вопросы, которые были удалены в течение последних 60 дней.
8. https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14190

   > На этой странице показаны ваши ответы, которые были удалены в течение последних 60 дней. Сюда также входят ответы на удалённые вопросы.